# Reading Excel cell Notes/Comments and writing into r dataframe column

Tags: r, excel

Issue: I need to read in excel workbook Notes/Comments for data cells as their own data column in R.

[image: Excel Note/Comment screenshot]

I have found my way to the Tidyxl package, but I cannot get the script to work when I'm loading the data.

I have started a GitHub thread to reference for input data, Rscript, & what I hope the end product will look like:

[Melunome/Excel-Notes-Comments-into-R](https://github.com/Melunome/Excel-Notes-Comments-into-R)

Comment: Do the cells that contain the comments contain any other `data`. i.e do you want to replace the cell contents with the comments?

Comment: The cells with comments have relevant information in them so I need both cell content and cell comment.

Answer (score 3):

The `xlsx` package supports this as well.

```
library(xlsx)
library(tidyverse)

wb <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(file = 'test_data_30oct2020 (1).xlsx')

sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[[1]]
rows <- getRows(sheet)
cells <- getCells(rows)


comments <- lapply(cells, getCellComment)


read_comments <- comments %>% 
  purrr::discard(is.null)

resp <- vector('list')

for (i in seq_along(read_comments)) {
  
  resp[[i]] <- read_comments[[i]]$getString()
  
}

resp
```

Comment: When I run the script I receive this error:Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

Comment: @melCGS you need to install java then install rJava package

Comment: Unfortunately the folks that I work for do not give permission to employees to download new/update software...this answer thread will have to standby until IT folks are back at work then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, getting R and java to play nice can be tricky depending on your setup.

Comment: @melCGS theoretically, `R CMD javareconf -e` should work ("If you do not have root privileges, run `R CMD javareconf -e`")

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be solved by any existing r package and you'd be better to pursue a `VBA` solution like the following solution that'll put the comment unto the cell:

```vb
Sub CommentToCell()
    ' loop through all the comments in the activesheet
    For Each cmt In ActiveSheet.Comments
        ' print the text of the comment unto the cell
        cmt.Parent = cmt.Text
    Next cmt
End Sub
```

I stand corrected the `Tidyxl` package has a functionality of importing comments it's documented in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyxl/vignettes/tidyxl.html):

```r
library(tidyxl)
path <- "path/of/ur.file.xlsx"
x <- xlsx_cells(path)
x[!is.na(x$comment), c("address", "comment")]
```

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  address comment                                          
  <chr>   <chr>                                            
1 P4      "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nTest Note"          
2 N6      "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nAnother stupid note"
3 O9      "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nsilly steer note"   
4 R11     "Mary Ashby:\r\nNo wt. - in 15SW"                
5 P4      "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nTest Note"          
6 N6      "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nAnother stupid note"
7 R11     "Mary Ashby:\r\nNo wt. - in 15SW"                
8 P4      "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nTest Note"          
9 R11     "Mary Ashby:\r\nNo wt. - in 15SW"
```

First we extract the row number from the address, then we `left_join` the excel file data, with the comments on equal `row_number`

```r
x[!is.na(x$comment), c("address", "comment")] %>%
     mutate(address=as.numeric(str_extract(address,"\\d+")))  -> cmts

readxl::read_excel(path) %>% mutate(address=row_number()) %>% left_join(cmts) -> ur.df

# just to see the result with the naked eye
ur.df %>% select(comment, everything())
```

```
# A tibble: 16 x 21
   comment Past  Section Treatment    ID `Tag Color` Owner notes
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>       <chr> <lgl>
 1  NA     15E   E       moderate      7 Black       John  NA   
 2  NA     15E   E       moderate      9 Black       John  NA   
 3  NA     15E   E       moderate     10 Black       John  NA   
 4 "Johns… 15E   E       moderate     20 Black       John  NA   
 5 "Johns… 15E   E       moderate     20 Black       John  NA   
 6 "Johns… 15E   E       moderate     20 Black       John  NA   
 7  NA     23E   E       heavy        33 Black       Bob   NA   
 8 "Johns… 23E   E       heavy        36 Black       Bob   NA   
 9 "Johns… 23E   E       heavy        36 Black       Bob   NA   
10  NA     23E   E       heavy        39 Black       Bob   NA   
11  NA     23E   E       heavy        49 Black       Bob   NA   
12 "Johns… 23W   W       light        57 Black       Cher… NA   
13  NA     23W   W       light        58 Black       Cher… NA   
14 "Mary … 23W   W       light        61 Black       Cher… NA   
15 "Mary … 23W   W       light        61 Black       Cher… NA   
16 "Mary … 23W   W       light        61 Black       Cher… NA
```

**Edit** loading all the sheets and retrieving their comments:

```r
library(readxl)
library(purrr)

# creating address from sheet name and row number
x[!is.na(x$comment), c("sheet", "address", "comment")] %>%
     mutate(address=paste0(sheet,"-", str_extract(address,"\\d+")), sheet=NULL)  -> cmts

# loading the data and adding an address column that contains the sheet name
# and row number in the format `sheet-rownum`
excel_sheets(path) %>%
   map_dfr(~ read_excel(path, sheet=.x) %>%
               mutate(address=paste0(.x,'-',row_number()))) -> ur.df

# joining the comments
ur.df %>% left_join(cmts) -> ur.df
ur.df %>% select(comment, address) %>% filter(!is.na(comment))
```

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  comment                                           address
  <chr>                                             <chr>  
1 "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nTest Note"           2003-4 
2 "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nAnother stupid note" 2003-6 
3 "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nsilly steer note"    2003-9 
4 "Mary Ashby:\r\nNo wt. - in 15SW"                 2003-11
5 "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nTest Note"           2002-4 
6 "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nAnother stupid note" 2002-6 
7 "Mary Ashby:\r\nNo wt. - in 15SW"                 2002-11
8 "Johnston, Melissa - ARS:\r\nTest Note"           2001-4 
9 "Mary Ashby:\r\nNo wt. - in 15SW"                 2001-11
```

Comment: This was my fear, I appreciate your quick response!

Comment: and do you have the comments in the same columns i.e you have one column that has comments

Comment: That is a possibility.

Comment: The cattle were periodically weighed so the date they were weighed was entered in as separate columns in excel one excel sheet (May 1, June 1), one workbook sheet per year. Steer ID was a separate column too, so if on Jun 1 weighing sample steer 1, 5, 9 had issues that needed to be recorded they recorded that information as a note/column in the cell that contained their weight record.

Comment: can you link sample data just first 10-20 rows of a single sheet, upload it to github and I'll see what I can do

Comment: Here is the link again if the one in the original post isn't working. https://github.com/Melunome/Excel-Notes-Comments-into-R

Comment: @melCGS there is no file other than `README`

Comment: Hmm, I uploaded an excel & csv before I posted here...I'll have to dig into why they're not showing up.

Comment: It appears you created a separate branch with the files on it.

Comment: That took forever, sorry. https://github.com/Melunome/Excel-Notes-Comments-into-R/tree/Melunome-Files Note: I'm a rookie on github...if THAT wasn't obvious.

Comment: I saw the xlsx_cells() in Tidyxl, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to pull out my comments...Error message: Error in file.exists(path) : invalid 'file' argument

Comment: instead of `titanic` with `"path/of/ur.file.xlsx"`

Comment: That worked, thanks! ...Now the hard part producing the "what_I_want_it_to_look_like.csv". The table produced a Row/Column name with comment as second column, but when I pull in this large dataset I need that comment to linkable to the weight value in the cell that the comment was written.

Comment: When I reviewed expected tags (those individuals who I knew had those comments assigned to them) I realized your script is close, but it appears to be only joining the comments by address (row #) into sheet 1 (year 2003), not by row within the appropriate sheet. I added x[!is.na(x$comment), c("sheet","address", "comment")] and joined to show that the comments are not being assigned to the correct steer within year.

Comment: @melCGS do you have a list of data.frames i.e a data.frame for each sheet. Also please consider to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @melCGS I corrected for this also check the link in the above comment